# Can't replace a package with Composer

Tags: composer-php

I made an improvement ([PR](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/pull/293) not merged yet) to an upstream library, [guzzlehttp/psr-7](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/psr7), that's a dependency of another package that I depend on, [spatie/crawler](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/crawler).

To force Composer to use my package instead of the upstream package, I tried the following:

- I [branched](https://github.com/BenMorel/psr7/tree/cache-to-string) my fork of the library (branch name: `cache-to-string`) and updated its `composer.json`:

  ```
  "name": "benmorel/guzzle-psr7",
  "replace": {
    "guzzlehttp/psr7": "1.6.*"
  }
  ```
- I updated my project's `composer.json` to use my fork instead:

  ```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/BenMorel/psr7"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "benmorel/guzzle-psr7": "dev-cache-to-string"
  }
  ```

And ran `composer update`, which fails with the following error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - The requested package benmorel/guzzle-psr7 could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

**How to fix this?**

Comment: Why did you change package name in your fork?

Comment: Because `guzzlehttp/psr-7` is not used by me directly, but referenced by one of my dependencies which requires a specific version, so I thought I had to `replace:` the original package, and that this required me to provide another package name. But I may be plain wrong, do you have another suggestion?

Comment: You don't need to change the name. You don't need to change `composer.json` of fork at all, all you need is to add your fork to `repositories` section and change constraint of required package to use your dev branch: `"guzzlehttp/psr7": "dev-cache-to-string"`. Composer will use `guzzlehttp/psr7` from your repository (fork).

Comment: This is where the problem lies: if I do that, Composer complains that it cannot find a suitable version for the `spatie/crawler` requirement (`^1.4`).

Comment: You may need to use alias for constraint: `"guzzlehttp/psr7": "dev-cache-to-string as 1.6.1"`.

Comment: @rob006 This works perfectly, thank you! Can you add an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change package name in your fork. You don't need to change `composer.json` of your fork at all. All you need is to add your fork to repositories section and change constraint of required package to use your dev branch:

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/BenMorel/psr7"
  }
],
"require": {
  "guzzlehttp/psr7": "dev-cache-to-string as 1.6.1"
}
```

Composer will override original `guzzlehttp/psr7` package by version from your repository.

Using alias for branch may be required if some other package require `guzzlehttp/psr7` - `dev-cache-to-string` will not match `^1.4`. If you use `dev-cache-to-string as 1.6.1` as a constraint, your branch will be detected as `1.6.1` release.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!